# Read failure Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm executing some query on my table and when I execute this query :

`select o_type from basic_data where oid4 = 1;`

I have this answer from Cassandra :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1277, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3822, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:74332)
    raise self._final_exception
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}`

But when I executue this query  :

`select o_type from basic_data where oid4 = 12192;`

I have that what i'm supposed to get :

`o_type`

`----------------------------------------------------------------`

`otype:G  ,otype_bin:-268435456;otype:GiC,otype_bin:-234881024;`

I dont know why I can only execute query on some rows, do you have some advice ?

Edit :

There is the error in my system.log
`ERROR [CompactionExecutor:3] 2017-05-24 13:40:50,901 CassandraDaemon.java:213 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:3,1,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Rows.collectStats(Rows.java:70) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$StatsCollector.applyToRow(BigTableWriter.java:223) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.applyOne(BaseRows.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.add(BaseRows.java:89) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.UnfilteredRows.add(UnfilteredRows.java:21) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Transformation.add(Transformation.java:142) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Transformation.apply(Transformation.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:156) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.append(SSTableRewriter.java:129) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.DefaultCompactionWriter.realAppend(DefaultCompactionWriter.java:65) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.append(CompactionAwareWriter.java:141) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:187) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:60) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:264) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]`

Comment: Try your query with tracing on and paste the trace in your question. Maybe it's because of tombstone

Comment: I had exactly the same message

Answer (score 0):

Can be due to reading taking to much time, try to run with higher timeout, in cqlsh, for example, run cqlsh with this option:

**cqlsh --request-timeout=3600**

Comment: Can you review debug log for errors? Also, try to run nodetool scrub and review the output.

Comment: There is the output of nodetool scrub :                                                      `WARN  08:26:27 Small commitlog volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 3839.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  08:26:27 Only 876,602MiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots`

Comment: Did it finished and this was the only output?

Comment: No, he didn't finish but it's actually the only output

Comment: Please review system.log and debug.log for output from the process.

Comment: No, I install directly Cassandra 3.6 and cqlsh 5.0.1

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to a newer version?

Comment: I've got the last version

Comment: Run upgrade ssstables after upgrading? (is it 3.11?)